# How to delete Emoji & Symbols and Dictation in menu bar?

Tags: xcode, macos, menu

How to delete Emoji & Symbols and Dictation in menu bar? I cannot find it in Xcode and I don't see it there but in the app I do.

[image: In app]

[image: In Xcode]

Comment: Please don't remove those menu items. You personally may have no use for them, but other Mac users expect those menu items to be available.

Comment: @chrstphrchvz That text field is used to convert between different bases of numbers, so it shouldn’t accept emojis.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Multiple questions nearly identical to this one have been asked purely because their askers found the menu items intrusive, and seemed unaware of the accessibility implications in removing them, so I left comments to dissuade future readers from attempting likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix, and no coding required.

Simply add one space after the title. Didn't think it will work.

[image: The Menu]

[image: In Xcode]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better solution that does not require "hacking" the Edit menu text. Simply add the following method to your AppDelegate...

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NSDisabledDictationMenuItem")
  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NSDisabledCharacterPaletteMenuItem")
}
```