# Remove Emoji & Symbol from edit menu in xamarin.mac / xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xcode-storyboard, xamarin.mac

Inside of the Edit application menu. Start Dictation and Emoji & Symbols are added.
[image]

I can't find anywhere in the storyboard where this should be removed. And hoped it could be done in the app delegate or similar instead.

I want to remove this as they are not supported.

Comment: First, have you read [Menus in Xamarin.Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/user-interface/menu)? Does what that doc describes in `Main.storyboard` look like what you see in your app's `Main.storyboard`? Is the `emoji Symbols` line under the `Edit` Menu, in that storyboard?

Comment: Yes that is the same

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped that if it showed in storyboard, you could somehow disable it there. But it is controlled by a "User Default", so do it this way:

On iOS, add to AppDelegate.cs:

```
    public override bool WillFinishLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // Remove "Emojis & Symbols" menu item.
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(true, "NSDisabledCharacterPaletteMenuItem");

        return base.WillFinishLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
    }
```

On Mac, according to comment below, add:

```
    public override void WillFinishLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        // Remove "Emojis & Symbols" menu item.
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(true, "NSDisabledCharacterPaletteMenuItem");

        return base.WillFinishLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
    }
```

NOTE: Not tested.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63018575/199364.

Comment: public override void WillFinishLaunching(NSNotification nSNotification)
        {
            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(true, "NSDisabledCharacterPaletteMenuItem");
        }

Comment: Above is how I got it to work m but it is very similar thank you. I had seen your 'Based on' but was unsure how to translate that into something xamarin understood. Thank you